# How to find the centroid of pixels with same color in a 360° video?

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-vision, 360-degrees

Let **I** be a `w x h` frame from a 360° video stream.
Let **R** be a red rectangle on that frame. **R** is smaller than the width of the image.

To compute the centroid of this rectangle we need to distinguish two cases:

- case 1 where **R** is on the edges
- case 2 where **R** is fully inside the frame

[image: Case 1 and 2 illustrated]

As you can see there will be a problem to compute the centroid with classical methods in case 1. Please note that I only care about horizontal overlapping.

For the moment I am doing like this. First we detect the first point we find and use it as a reference, then we normalize `dx` which is the difference between a point and the reference and then we accumulate:

```
width = frame.width
rectangle_pixel = (255,0,0)
first_found_coord = (-1,-1)
centroid = (0,0)
centroid_count = 0

for pixel, coordinates in image:
  if(pixel != rectangle_pixel): 
    continue
  if(first_found_coord == (-1,-1)):
    first_found_coord = coordinates 
    centroid = coordinates
    continue

  dx = coordinates.x - first_found_coord.x
  if(dx > width/2):
    dx -= width
  else if(dx < - width/2):
    dx -= width

  centroid += (dx, coordinates.y)
  centroid_count++


final_centroid = centroid / centroid_count
```

But it doesn't work as expected. Where is the problem, is there a faster solution ?

Comment: There can actually be a third case when the rectangle crosses a corner, and is separated into 4 parts.

Comment: True in theory but I'll never encounter this case in my scenarios. "(...) I only care about horizontal overlapping."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm computing the bounding boxes in the same scope, I do it in two steps.
I first accumulate the coordinates of the pixels of interest. Then when I'm checking for overlapping bounding boxes, I subtract the with for each overlapping colors on the right half of the image. So I end up with a completed but slided rectangle.

At the end I divide by the number of point found per color. If the result is negative I shift it by the size of width of the image.

---

Alternatively:

```
def get_centroid(image, interest_color):
    acc_x = 0
    acc_y = 0
    count = 0
    first_pixel = (0,0)

    for (x,y, color) in image:
      if(color not in interest_color):
        continue

      if(count == 0):
        first_pixel = (x,y)

      dx = x - first_pixel.x

      if(dx > L/2)
        dx -= L
      else if (dx < -L/2)
        dx += L

      acc_x += x
      acc_y += y
      count++

    non_scaled_result = acc_x / count, acc_y / count
    result = non_scaled_result + first_pixel

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on transition points, i.e when you move from red to non red, or in the other way. To capture the horizontal center, I needed the following information :

`gridSize.x` : width of the space where rectangles can live.
`w` : width of your rectangle.

PseudoCode:

```
redPixel = (255,0,0);

transitionPoints = [];
betweenTransitionsColor = -1;

// take i and i+1 pixel+position, increment i by one at each step. 
for (pixel1, P1), (pixel1, P2) in gridX : // horizontal points for a fixed `y` 
  if pixel1 != pixel2: // one is red, the other white
     nonRedPosition = (pixel1 != redPixel ? P1 : P2)
     transitionPoints.append(nonRedPosition)
     continue
  if(transitionPoints.length == 1 && betweenTransitionsColor == -1):
     betweenTransitionsColor = pixel2

  if transitionPoints.length == 2:
      break

//Case where your rectangle is on the edge (left or right)
if(transitionPoints.length == 1):
  if(abs(transitionPoints[0].x - w) < 2):
    xCenter = w/2
  else:
    xCenter = gridSize.x - w/2

else:
  [tP1, tP2] = transitionPoints

  // case 1 : The rectangle is splitted
  if betweenTransitionsColor != redPixel:
    xCenter = (tP2.x - gridSize.x + tP1.x)/2
  else:
    xCenter = (tP1.x + tP1.x)/2
```

Note :

you must start at a `y` position where you could get red pixels. This shouldn't be very hard to achieve. If your `rectangle's height` is bigger than `gridSize.y/2`, you can begin at `gridSize.y/2`. Otherwise, you can search for a first red pixel, and set y to the corresponding position.

Comment: Transition point based techniques won't work in my case since the color blob might not be a smooth rectangle but rather fragmented. Might be interesting for others, thanks for sharing.